# Sequelize doesn't save included objects

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, sequelize.js

If I do this unit testing,

```
  test('it saves included instances', async() => {
    /* Get "water" composition */
    const compositions = await _compositions.findAll(
        {include: [{model: _elements, where: {name: 'water'}}, _atoms]});

    /**
     * compositions[0] -> Hydrogren
     * compositions[1] -> Oxygen
     */
    let hydrogen = compositions[0].get('atom');
    /* rename "Hydrogen" to "My super Hydrogen" */
    hydrogen.name = 'My super Hydrogen';

    /* save the composition */
    compositions[0].save();

    /* Get a fresh Hydrogen Instance from the database */
    hydrogen = await _atoms.find({where: {symbol: 'H'}});
    expect(hydrogen.name)
        .to.equal('My super Hydrogen', 'wrong, the value is still Hydrogen');
  });
```

I would expect the value to be equal to the value previously saved from the related object.

The property `atom` of a `composition` is a foreign key :

```
compositionModel.belongsTo(await getAtomModel(), {foreignKey: 'atom_id'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are updating an object in Sequelize, you should call `.update` on the instance itself

```
test('it saves included instances', async() => {
  const compositions = await _compositions.findAll(
      {include: [{model: _elements, where: {name: 'water'}}, _atoms]});
  let hydrogen = compositions[0].get('atom');

  let newName = 'My super Hydrogen';
  compositions[0].update({
      name: newName
  });

  /* Get a fresh Hydrogen Instance from the database */
  hydrogen = await _atoms.find({where: {symbol: 'H'}});
  expect(hydrogen.name)
      .to.equal(newName);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the late reply. `compositions[0].atom.update({ name: newName });` worked. However I misjudged the behavior, I thought I could just save the parent and included objects would get updated as well but I guess `include` is just meaningful when fetching relational data from the database. Unlike Hibernate for Java.

Comment: No, the reason is because you were updating the instance object, but not the data itself. Technically, if you had updated `hydrogen.dataValues.name = 'some new name'` that would have worked, but it's better to call `.update`. Anyway, did this answer your question?